# Can this Houdini curl noise flow effect be done in Blender?

Tags: particles, physics, force-fields, particle-edit-mode

Can we make the particles flow across the surface of a sphere like this? Maybe using forces? I tried using a negative force field to attract the particles to the surface and tried using the vertex force to make them move in a circular way but the particles seem to move circular in a plane and not the sphere. [Here's the original animation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RG-Ybbn0J_c).

[image]

Comment: [Midge Sinnaeve](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w8jOBRMlaTU) might give you a kick-off. Belnder texture influence does actually have a 'curl' setting.

Comment: I don't understand why this question got so many upvotes. Is it just because of the [tweet](https://twitter.com/StackBlender/status/1514076073239187461)? Sorry to say but this is a poorly worded question. The title is not meaningful at all and the question relies on an external link. Good luck imagining "this Houdini effect" (quote from the title) when the link is broken. The tag "blender-internal-render-engine" is for the old Blender 2.79 version from 2017. Do you really use this old version?

Comment: @Blunder: you are totally right, the question is poorly worded, but the effect looks really cool ;) so one upvote came from me - and he is a SE beginner...so don't be too hard ;)

Comment: Entagma covers an approximation of curl noise in Blender very nicely [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MMwzKylfM8g). Edited your title for searchability. Hope that's OK.